# Add an image to formData in Javascript. (Without input type file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm Working on a Cordova/Ionic Application and I'm trying to add a picture in a formData. It's working great with an input type.

**With Input Type**

```
<input id="photo" type="file" accept="image/*">   

formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

I've tried without input,but it's not working.... I Really need to make it work in that way.

**Without Input Type**

```
<img src="img.png" id="imgID" />

formData.append('image', $('#imgID')[0].files[0]);
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score -1):

Since the image is displayed on the page, it has a known URL — it (by definition) isn't a file stored on the visitor's computer. So just submit the URL to your application, and if necessary download the image from that URL within the application.